# Swift - Why is symbol not found

Tags: swift, macos, dylib, dyld, missing-symbols

The app I'm working on runs fine on macOS 10.14.3, but when I run it on macOS 10.14.4 I get this error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$SBOWV
Referenced from: {path to linked library}
Expected in: /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib
```

How can I go about figuring out what is really happening and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 10.2? What version of Swift?

Comment: Xcode 10.2, the bundled static libraries are compiled using the Swift 4.2 Release toolchain and so is the project itself

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by mixing of Swift 4 and Swift 5.

$SBOWV is an internal routine in the Swift standard library in Swift 4, but is not present anymore in Swift 5. Sounds like you might have object code that was compiled with Swift 4, but, you are trying to run on a system with the Swift 5 libraries.  This is all part of the ABI stability changes made in Swift 5, and the ability now to use ABI-stable frameworks in Swift 5 and beyond (on MacOS, Linux is not ABI-stable, yet).

Ensure the app is compiled with Xcode 10.2.x compiler. One possible thing is the compile-toolchains was set to a non-standard compiler.